# How to load the dump.sql files on docker-compose up (MariaDB)

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm tring to run docker-compose up in the code below but i'm unable to load the dump.sql data into the database.

This is my docker compose file ...

I tried this with Mysql and it works perfectly but with mariadb i'm unable to load the dump files

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  apache_server:
    build:
      context: './docker/apache/'
    links:
      - mariadb_server:mysqldb
    depends_on:
      - mariadb_server
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./docker/apache/virtualhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
      - ./docker/apache/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    container_name: apache_server

  mariadb_server:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci','--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mariadb-dump/dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
      # i tried with this also
      # - ./docker/mariadb-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "18906:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbtest
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    container_name: mariadb_server
```

Comment: Well, mariadb is **not** mysql - to contrary of popular belief. Mariadb is a **fork** of mysql. Your sql script was probably created for mysql and contains sql statements that are not syntactically correct for mariadb. You need to identify these sql statements and change them to comply with mariadb syntax.

Comment: No, the sql script is for mariadb, I'm switching to mariabd because we only used the docker for development and on production we used mariadb... the dump.sql is from the mariadb server

Comment: Could it be the custom `command` you specify? The mariadb [Dockerfile](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.template) calls the [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) script which does the processing of the SQL init files. I've used a similar `./docker/mariadb-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` volume and it worked.